# Apache 2.2 does not load custom module

Tags: c++, apache2

i build an custom apache module mod_spnego using visual studio 2015 and c++ sources, using apache 2.2.31 libs (apr, apr_util) and header files on testing machine. I loaded that module successfully in that apache 2.2.31 on testing machine, but after migrating module on production machine, it fails to load and apache 2.2.31 on that machine throws misleading error "The specified module cannot be found"

I believe, that underlying error is with some missing os .lib, or incompatible os lib, because apache 2.2.31 libs on production machine are the same as on testing machine.

One difference during compile was necessisty to add wss2tcip.header file. Linker then linked ws2_32.lib, but this library is not on production machine

I am really new to c++. Please help me find out the reason why apache on production machine does not load module.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that issue. Production machine missed vc15 redistributables. After installing vc15, module loaded ok